# how to set timeout for httpwebrequest in C# , WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I would like to set a timeout value for httpwebrequest in my C# WinRT code. But httpwebrequest is not available in WinRT. so how please let me know how to set the timeout value for the HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to make your request. It has a TimeOut property you can set to your liking.

You can also use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, and it also have a [TimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

In most cases, HttpClient is the way to go, as it is easier to use and you don't need the level of customization the HttpWebRequest provides.

Comment: so you mean to say that there is no way to set timeout if I use HttpWebRequest ?

Comment: I'm sorry, i took for granted your affirmation that "httpwebrequest is not available in WinRT". Turns out it is available. I edited my answer accordingly. Anyway, in most cases, use HttpClient: it's far easier to use and can make multiple requests if need be.

Answer (score 0):

to set timeout to your webrequest you need to set HttpWebRequest.Timeout and it's all .

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("your url");
myHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 1000 ;
```